# read and write files in java using separate threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have created two threads and modified the run function so that one thread reads one line and the other writes the same line to the new file. This happens till the whole file is copied. The problem i am getting is that even though i have used variables to control that the threads execute one by one but still the threads are executing unevenly i.e one thread executes multiple times and then the control transfers. Any solutions i have attached the code. I am new to java as it is only for class assignment so the code might not be the most optimized.

```
  public class thread1 extends Thread {
    //To create producer and consumer as threads
        //Shared variable
        public static int x = 0;//checks if all lines are read                                      
        public static String line; /holds lines from file
        public static int j = 0;//variable to switch between threads based upon its value

        public thread1(String threadName) {     //Constuctor
            super(threadName);      //Call to constructor of Thread class
        }

        public void run() {

            while (x != -1)
            {
                if (Thread.currentThread().getName().contains("Reader")) {
                    if (x != -1&&j==0)
                    {
                   j=1;
                    String fileName = "d:/salfar.txt";


                    try {
                        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
                        FileReader fileReader =
                                new FileReader(fileName);

                        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                                new BufferedReader(fileReader);

                        for (int check = 0; check <= x; check++) {

                            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                        }
                        if (line == null) {
                            x = -1;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(line);

                            x++;
                        }


                        // Always close files.
                        bufferedReader.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                        System.out.println(
                                "Unable to open file '"
                                + fileName + "'");
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.out.println(
                                "Error reading file '"
                                + fileName + "'");
                        // Or we could just do this: 
                        // ex.printStackTrace();

                    }
                    }

                    yield();
                } 
                else if (Thread.currentThread().getName().contains("writer")) {
    if (x != -1 && line != null&&j==1)
    {
                    j=0;

                    String fileName = "d:/salfar1.txt";

                    try {
                        // Assume default encoding.
                        FileWriter fileWriter =
                                new FileWriter(fileName, true);

                        // Always wrap FileWriter in BufferedWriter.
                        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =
                                new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

                        // Note that write() does not automatically
                        // append a newline character.
                        bufferedWriter.write(line);
                        bufferedWriter.newLine();
                        System.out.println("y");
                        // Always close files.
                        bufferedWriter.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.out.println(
                                "Error writing to file '"
                                + fileName + "'");
                        // Or we could just do this:
                        // ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
    }     
                    Thread.yield();
                }
                else{}
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            thread1 p = new thread1("Reader");
            thread1 c = new thread1("writer");

            p.start();
            c.start();


        }
    }


    Thanks
```

Comment: because unfortunately  thats what **Threads** do !!!

Comment: Show us your relevant code. It's also a bad idea to read a line in one thread and then write it in another, since that makes it essentially sequential. If instead you were to read into a buffer, you could have the threads work in a more parallelized way.

Comment: post your code [ so far what you've done]

Comment: and you are stuck in `producer and consumer problem` use wait and notify  logic to get rid of it and post some code to get help

Comment: i have attached the code . I am new to java as it is only for class assignment so the code might not be the most optimized.

Comment: @Kayaman it is for an assignment that's why I have no choice but to implement it this way in sequential manner.

Comment: @SalmanFarooq Make a separate class for the reader and for the writer, otherwise you'll just confuse yourself.

Comment: @kayaman as I mentioned it is an assignment so can it be done by one class only ???

Comment: @SalmanFarooq It can be done with a single class sure, but you'll have a higher chance of messing things up. You can use a couple of static inner classes instead, and still have all the code in a single file. Your `Thread.yield()` calls are also useless, and I suspect there's a lot more problems with your code, so putting them into separate classes will help both you and the people who are helping you.

Comment: that's some nice info @Kayaman I will discuss it with the teacher. thanks for the help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot control the order of thread execution. However, to perform read and write operation via separate threads, you should use BlockingQueue which has the following properties:

**A Queue that additionally supports operations that wait for the queue to become non-empty when retrieving an element, and wait for space to become available in the queue when storing an element.**

**ReaderThread will read from the input file.**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class ReaderThread implements Runnable{

  protected BlockingQueue<String> blockingQueue = null;

  public ReaderThread(BlockingQueue<String> blockingQueue){
    this.blockingQueue = blockingQueue;     
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    BufferedReader br = null;
     try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("./inputFile.txt")));
            String buffer =null;
            while((buffer=br.readLine())!=null){
                blockingQueue.put(buffer);
            }
            blockingQueue.put("EOF");  //When end of file has been reached

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(InterruptedException e){

        }finally{
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


  }



}
```

**WriterThread will write to output file.**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class WriterThread implements Runnable{

  protected BlockingQueue<String> blockingQueue = null;

  public WriterThread(BlockingQueue<String> blockingQueue){
    this.blockingQueue = blockingQueue;     
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    PrintWriter writer = null;

    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter(new File("outputFile.txt"));

        while(true){
            String buffer = blockingQueue.take();
            //Check whether end of file has been reached
            if(buffer.equals("EOF")){ 
                break;
            }
            writer.println(buffer);
        }               


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(InterruptedException e){

    }finally{
        writer.close();
    } 

  }

}
```

**From Launcher class start your multithreaded read and write.**

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class Launcher {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(1024);

    ReaderThread reader = new ReaderThread(queue);
    WriterThread writer = new WriterThread(queue);

    new Thread(reader).start();
    new Thread(writer).start();

  }

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solutions. My idea is to use the actually file name that our threads will be reading and writing to. There is only one issue that we need to make sure of, that no two threads are trying to operate on the same file. The solution to this is to simply have a synchronized code block in your run method.

We must recall that Strings are not mutable in Java. Consider the following:

```
String s1 = "test.txt";
String s2 = "test.txt";
```

Now, we must ask our selves how does the jvm reuse the immutable "test.txt". In this case both s1 & s2 String objects point to the same "test.txt".

Understanding this concept will also do the trick for us:

```
public class Client {

public static void main( String args [] ) {

    String filename = "test.txt";
    String filename2 = "test.txt";

    Reader reader = new Reader( filename ) ; 
    Writer writer = new Writer( filename2 ) ;

    while(true) {
        reader.run();
        writer.run();
    }

  }
} 

public class Writer implements Runnable {

public String filename; 

public Writer( String filename ) {
    this.filename = filename; 
}

@Override
public void run() { 

    synchronized( this.filename ) {
        System.out.println( "writing to a file:" + this.filename );  
    }  

 }
}


public class Reader implements Runnable {

public String filename; 

public Reader( String filename ) {
    this.filename = filename; 
}

@Override
public void run() { 

    synchronized( this.filename ) {
        System.out.println( "reading a file:" + this.filename );
    } 

}
}
```